# Django Query Set in Deep with exclude

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

i have three classes
Product have many Descriptions and each model have many stores
what i want to do

```
select all products but store.qty value > 0
```

I've tried

```
pr = Product.objects.all().exclude(Product__Product_description__qty > 0)
```

how can i do that ?

```
class Product
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Product_description
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

class Store
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.ForeignKey(Product_description)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: why going throu the "exclude qty > 0" way, when you can use "get all qty <= 0"? i guess you're searching for all products without any stored quantity, so qty = 0 (negative if you allow to order for a product which is not present)

Answer (score 2):

```
pr = Product.objects.filter(Product_description__qty__lte = 0)
```

Or if you really must use exclude:

```
pr = Product.objects.exclude(Product_description__qty__gt = 0)
```

`all()` is not necessary in either case; you just end up building an untriggered proxy that goes into building the filter/exclude queryset afterward.  It wastes memory and CPU, but otherwise does nothing.  Only the `.delete()` operator requires a working `all()` queryset, but it's a special case designed explicitly to avoid the accidental destruction of datasets.

The [Django Queryset API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) documentation is very readable.

Django convention is to name your class `ProductDescription`.

This seems like a backward hierarchy.  Why would stores have "product descriptions?"  Isn't that metadata on the product itself, and what you care about is that the stores have a certain quantity of product?  Or are these product variants, i.e you want to find all the products for which stores have at least one green or blue or orange one?  Something tells me that your project needs a careful re-think.

Comment: "Something tells me that your project needs a careful re-think."  The most important line in this answer.